# Using harsh with generated code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have code in `@snippet.code`, and I want to highlight it with [harsh](http://github.com/michaeledgar/harsh):

```
:harsh
  #!harsh theme = lazy
  = @snippet.code
```

However, this just highlights `@snippet.code`, so the output is:

```
<pre class="lazy"><span class="Keyword">=</span> <span class="Variable"><span class="Variable">@</span>snippet</span>.code&#x000A;</pre>
```

How can I use Harsh with generated code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to print out the contents of @snippet.code

It would help to know what templating engine you are using. Try:

```
:harsh
  #!harsh theme = lazy
  <%= @snippet.code %>
```

This should work if erb get to the code *before* harsh.

Comment: I am using HAML, your code would thus raise a syntax error :)